# BaseInFilter separates values by comma. What if a value has a comma?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using `BaseInFilter` and it works great. I am able to have URLs like `/producs/?title=some_title,some_other_title`. But what if a title has a comma? Can I somehow encode it? Or the only way for me to use ids (which I really really do not want to do because of SEO and readability). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you encode it `%2c`, but you can simply add the same key multiple times, so `?title=some_title&title=some_other_title`

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow encode it?

You can encode it with [*percent-encoding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The comma is encoded as `%2c`:

```
/products/?title=some_title%2csome_other_title
```

You can however also repeat the same key multiple times:

```
/products/?title=some_title&title=some_other_title
```

and obtain at the Django side a list of values for `title` with:

```
request.GET.getlist('title')
```

Comment: what if `some_title` is `some,_title`? I would need then `some%2c_title,some_title2` but it doesn't work

Comment: @Tomas: no, since then that comma is also interpreted as just a simple comma, since a URL can *not* contain a comma. That is one of *the* reasons why you better mention the same parameter multiple times, since then you can write all possible characters (in percent encoding) for a value.